# The raw headers observer url request count has grown larger than expected, Angular2, Electron

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, electron, chromium

After a certain number of HTTP request with RXJS (around 495 or so), in Angular 2, inside Electron, I get this error on the console. It doesn't matter if I space them by 500ms or 1000ms, once 495 http requests have been performed, this error shows up:

[15056:0427/015919.996:WARNING:netlog_observer.cc(64)] The raw headers observer url request count has grown larger than expected, resetting

```
    return Observable.interval(500).flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(this.api_adress + '/status', options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    });
```

I haven't found a suitable solution, as the information on this error is very limited on Google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `netlog_observer.cc` is part of Chromium but I don't know what exactly it means. Maybe you have too many pending requests? https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr_1/content/browser/loader/netlog_observer.cc#61

Comment: Weird. I do generate HTTP request for status updates and so on, but regardless of how much time they take for them to be consumed/executed, there comes a time where it stops working after the same number of request.